# Passing variable as argument

Tags: tikz-pgf, expansion

I need to pass a variable to a command, but I cannot get it to work. Here is a short example that shows that #1 can be sent to a command, but not a variable that is a copy of #1. Why is this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\pgfkeys
    { /mypgf/.cd
    , options/.store in = \options
    , options/.get = \options
    }

\newcommand{\img}[2][]{
    \pgfkeys{/mypgf/.cd, options=#1}
    \def \test {#1}

    % This works:
    \includegraphics[#1]{#2}

    % This does not work:
    \includegraphics[\options]{#2}

    % This does not work either:
    \includegraphics[\test]{#2}
}

\begin{document}

\img[width=0.1\textwidth]{image.png}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! `\includegraphics` does not expand its first argument.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in @egreg's comment, `\includegraphics` does not expand its first argument.  A judicious use of `\expandafter` resolves that part of the problem.

But also, `\pgfkeys` is getting confused by the `=` buried within the value you're passing.  Try something like:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\pgfkeys
    {/mypgf/.cd,
      options/.store in = \options,
      options/.get = \options,
    }

\newcommand{\img}[2][]{
    \pgfkeys{/mypgf/.cd, options={#1}}
    \def \test {#1}
    %%\typeout{===>"\options"|#1}%%

    % This works:
    \includegraphics[#1]{#2}

    % This does not work:
    \expandafter\includegraphics\expandafter[\options]{#2}

    % This does not work either:
    \expandafter\includegraphics\expandafter[\test]{#2}
}

\begin{document}

\img[width=\dimexpr0.1\textwidth]{example-image}

\end{document}
```

By uncommenting `\typeout` you can better see what's being passed to `\options` as you wrote it.  By wrapping `#1` in brackets, `\options` receives the correct string.

Also, I would put the commas, from within `\pgfkeys{....}`, at the end of the lines to prevent unwanted white space creeping into the values of your keys.

Comment: Sweet! Thanks :) But nothing seemed to happen when I uncommented the \typeout

Comment: `\typeout` writes to the terminal and your log file.  It's not that important and not necessary for your fix.  It's just useful sometimes when trying to debug something.  I put the `===>` to make it stand out a bit more on the command line.  If you're not compiling from the command line, then you can always look in the log file.