# Input variable as argument in metapost script?

Tags: loops, programming, metapost, scripts, variable

I would like to pass input parameters into my .mp script.
For example, instead of running:

```
mpost script.mp
```

I want to run something like:

```
mpost script.mp 1 1 2 diamand
```

Where "1 1 2 diamond" are 4 input parameters telling the script what to do.

At the moment I have things like:

```
numeric showindices
showindices := 0;
%showindices := 1;

string drawingmode
drawingmode := "diamond";
%drawingmode := "square";
```

I am then running "mpost script.mp" with showindices=0 un-commented, and then separately with showindices=1 un-commented. Likewise I'm running it with drawingmode=diamond un-commented, and then separately with drawingmode=square un-commented.

There's 10 drawing modes and various "switches" similar to showindices, so I don't want to just keep un-commenting and re-commenting different lines. I also don't want to copy and paste the whole script so many times. Perhaps you'll say I can run through all these combinations in a loop, but is there a way to just pass in arguments from the command line, if I wanted for example, "square" drawingmode and "1" for showindices ?

---

<sup>Note: This quesiton is not a duplicate of: 
[Passing variable as argument](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/163265/passing-variable-as-argument)</sup>
<sup>Note: This quesiton is also not a duplicate of: 
[Input Command and Declaring Variables](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/417683/input-command-and-declaring-variables)</sup>

Comment: Computers usually don't guess at the intentions of the user. You need to make a shell script that does the assignments behind the scenes and *knows* what parameters the value should be assigned to. Then it will build a command line such as `mpost "numeric showindices;showindices:=$2;string drawingmode; drawingmode=$5; input $1"` and run it.

Comment: @egreg: Sounds interesting, but I don't really understand what you are saying.

Comment: The questions you are saying are not duplicates don't have anything to do with MetaPost, so there is no way they could be duplicates at all.

Comment: @egreg Please write an answer.

Comment: @HenriMenke Done

Answer (score 2):

You can call `mpost` with the command line

```
mpost '\numeric showindices;showindices:=1;string drawingmode;drawingmode:="diamond";input script'
```

The initial backslash is required in order that `mpost` doesn't interpret `numeric` as a file name.

This can become complicated with more than two parameters, so you could write down a shell script such as

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
mpost "\\ \
numeric showindices; showindices:=$2; \
string drawingmode; drawingmode:="$3"; \
input $1"
```

Save this as the file `runscript` and call it from the command line like

```
sh runscript script.mp 1 \"diamond\"
```

The shell will split the input after `sh runscript` at words, assigning them the variables `1`, `2`, `3` and so on. Note how quotes should be used in order to pass “real” quotes to the script.

If you make the file `runscript` executable, you can also call it like

```
./runscript script.mp 1 \"diamond\"
```

and you can save `runscript` in a place where the shell looks for executable programs or scripts, then calling it as

```
runscript script.mp 1 \"diamond\"
```

Comment: thank you. Please let me go through it properly and try it out. I may not be able to until January because my office is closed for the holiday season.